# R studio crashes when Rcpp is run

Tags: r, data.table, rstudio, rcpp

I understand RO is a not debugging platform but I am new to Rcpp so hopefully someone can help me why this error happens since I am not sure whether it is to do with Rstudio or Rccp function.

A sample data is here. The reason I am putting the original data is to ensure that people can reproduce the errors that I am having.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/s9xgu5h0qfojy9q/test.csv?dl=0

```
test <- read.csv("test.csv")
test <- data.table(test)
```

A function that I got from one of my postings using Rcpp is below:

```
Rcpp::cppFunction('
              List WRSI(NumericVector daily_tawc,
              NumericVector TAWC,
              NumericVector Precp,
              NumericVector swc,
              NumericVector PETc) {

              int n = daily_tawc.length();
              NumericVector SW(n);
              NumericVector PAW(n);
              NumericVector AETc(n);

              double SW_ini_glob = daily_tawc[0];
              double SW_max_glob = TAWC[0];

              SW[0] = SW_ini_glob;

              for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {

              PAW[i] = SW[i-1] + Precp[i];

              if (PAW[i] >= swc[i]) {
              AETc[i] = PETc[i];
              } else {
              AETc[i] = PAW[i]/swc[i]*PETc[i];
              }

              if (AETc[i] > PAW[i]) {
              AETc[i] = PAW[i];
              }

              SW[i] = SW[i-1] + Precp[i] - AETc[i];

              if(SW[i] > SW_max_glob) {
              SW[i] = SW_max_glob;
              }

              if(SW[i] < 0) {
              SW[i] = 0;
              }
              }
              return Rcpp::List::create(Rcpp::Named("SW") = SW,
              Rcpp::Named("PAW") = PAW,
              Rcpp::Named("AETc") = AETc);
              }')
```

When I run the above function for the test data,

```
  test[, c("SW","PAW","AETc") := WRSI(daily_tawc,
                                       TAWC,
                                       Precp,
                                       swc,
                                       PETc), keyby = .(state.id,meso.id,micro.id,mun.id,year)]
```

[image]

Everytime the Rstudio crashes. I was wondering if someone could tell me what is it that is wrong? What are the likely reasons that Rstudio crashes while running the above function. I am not sure if there is something in the function that is crashing my Rstudio.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without going into details or searching for duplicates:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
```

This *looks* wrong. It should probably read

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
```